# Efficient allreduce is not supported for 2 IndexedSlices

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, multi-gpu

I am trying to run a Subclassed Keras Model on multiple GPUs. The code is running as expected, however, the following "warning" crops up during the execution of the code:

"Efficient allreduce is not supported for 2 IndexedSlices"

What does this mean? I followed the Multi-GPU tutorial on Tensorflow 2.0 Beta guide. I am also using the Dataset API for my input pipeline.

Comment: Did you discover this in the end? :)

Comment: anyone from Tensorflow team can answer this?

Comment: This might be a relevant thread: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41898